# How to use search(in google map) between 2 activities using intent(or something)

Tags: android, google-maps

i want a make application

1. MainActivity( EditText )

   - put address
2. SearchActivity( google map )

   - searching and movecamera using address from MainActivity

like this.

but i can't find any way....

Comment: You need to get your hands on some tutorials first

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dr0zEmuDuIk

Whatch this video so you can understand how this google maps works

After that you can add a editText in MainActivity and when you click the button to search the address, you create a new map and you send the address 
exemple:

MainActivity:

```
String address = editText.getText().toString();
Intent Map = new Intent(this,maps.class);
Map.putExtra("address",address);
startActivity(Map);
```

SearchActivity:

```
Intent i =  getIntent();
String address = i.getStringExtra("address");
```

I think this is all correct,
Any doubt just say